# SQL ORDER by `no` with NULLs at the end

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have got a MySql query that orders me results by `no` column (int, can be null).
Simple example:

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY no ASC`

I would like to get a resultset sorted like

`1, 2, 3, 10, 52, 66, NULL, NULL, NULL`

but I get

`NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, 2, 3, 10, 52, 66`

Is it possible with SQL query ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
ORDER BY ISNULL(no),no;
```

Comment: Why not just "ORDER BY ISNULL(no), no;"? ISNULL already returns 1 if null or 0 if not.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `CASE` statement to tweak ordering:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY case when no is null then 2 else 1 end, no
```

This orders on "nullableness" first, and `no` second.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ISNULL(field), field ASC;
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer because of its simplicity

Comment: Well, now that the user "YOU" changed his answer, the accepted answer is now as good as this one ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY COALESCE(no,999999) ASC
```

Just replace the 999999 with something larger if your numbers are naturally bigger than that.

Comment: Bad one when my `no` achieves `999999 + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I got it:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE no IS NOT NULL ORDER BY no ASC
UNION

SELECT * FROM table WHERE no IS NULL`

Or is there any better way ?

Comment: But with complicated query - few `JOIN`s it will be scared. :)

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY no ASC NULLS LAST`