# Order By with NULL Values Last

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to simply sort the table by the column "names" with NULL fields IN THE END.

I tried this:

```
SELECT *       
FROM Table 
ORDER BY (CASE
            WHEN Name IS NULL THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
          END), 
         name
```

The problem is that there is more than 1 nullable column, so obviously the above code don't resolve the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880278/sql-order-by-no-with-nulls-at-the-end

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Orderby a number, Nulls last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051602/mysql-orderby-a-number-nulls-last)

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8510632/php-mysql-order-by-date-but-empty-dates-last-not-first

Comment: yeah but in my case i have more than 1 nullable column, that's why those solutions don't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OR` operator to join multiple columns

```
order by (isnull(column1) or isnull(column2) or ..)
```

Comment: @Jonhz, can you create a demo sqlfiddle?

Comment: I'll try to create a sqlfiddle. I think another solution would be to change all NULL's into empty ("").But how could I do that?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but not exactly what i need... I wanted to order by the column A and all NULL in A in the end, like this: http://s28.postimg.org/oemqe1g0d/image.jpg

Comment: @Jonhz, try `order by isnull(columnA), columnA`

Comment: oh maaaaaan i'm feeling so dumb right now.. i did tried that before but I was doing another thing wrong... i got it now, thanks!